# good php-based toolkit or backend software for paypal subscription management?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, subscriptions

Does anyone know of a good "toolkit", set of pre-built classes, or otherwise some type of php software that can help manage subscriptions/recurringpayments for paypal?  This would be for a web-based service that users subscribe to and pay monthly.

Open source is preferable and really I'm looking for something that can be edited or customized from the server side as needed.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried scanning through paypal's tutorials, i believe they have their own implementations in php

Comment: they provide some sdk for php see at their downloads

Answer (score 0):

Are these the sort of things you are looking for?

http://codecanyon.net/item/membership-manager-pro/91421 
http://www.withinweb.com/phpsecurearea/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same some years ago and all I could find was very poorly written code.
I ended creating my own solution based on those code examples (PayPal has code on its website, extremely poor written but can be used as a start)

PayPal offers many different APIs and some of them are not really well thought through.
For example, by default, it offers a redirection API which will redirect the user to your website with a few parameters to proof the payment was done.
I used that as a start and found that at least 1/3 of the users do not wait for the redirection and close the tab (or cancel it) -> all of them will not execute that code.

PayPal offers a website notification API which works asynchronous to to the payment.
Their backend will send a IPN message to your registered URL with all parameters required for each payment (and all other transaction based events).

Look here for the IPN API:
https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples
it includes PHP code (you'll not want to use, you just want to learn from that poor code)